# set padding with percentage android

Tags: android

i want to set padding of an element in android in order to have 3.2% in left , right and bottom padding, i've done some research but i didn't get anything interesting , here what i've tried.

```
           Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                int width = display.getWidth();
                int height = display.getHeight();

                FrameLayout rel = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabcontent);
                double width_pas= width*3.2;
                double height_pas=height*3.2;
                rel.setPadding(width_pas,0,width_pas,height_pas);
```

but i get error in the setpadding , it only accepte integers , but i need to set margin at 3.2
hope you can help me.

Comment: you can only set pixel count by setPadding function. so pixel count is integer. you can not give double pixel. you have to cast it somehow. why you just dont do "int width_pas = (int)(width * 3.2);"

Comment: if i do that , i'll get 3% of padding not 3.2% that the probleme so i juste need to know if there is a alternative solution for that problem.

Comment: there is not alternative solution. pixel is smallest part of screen that you can set a color on it. so, you can not set something on half of pixel. you have to specify exactly which pixel will be drawn. btw, casting does not mean %3.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. If you want to calculate 3.2% of width/height you should multiply a specific value by `0.032` and not by `3.2`.
2. You cannot set float padding (see [Adem's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957427/set-padding-with-percentage-android#comment53740074_32957427) comment)
3. It's not true that if you use `ints` instead of `floats/doubles` you will end up with `3%` of padding instead of `3.2%`. It depends on what you're gonna round. If you calculate your paddings this way:

```
int width_pas = Math.round(width * 0.032f);
int height_pas = Math.round(height * 0.032f);
```

you will end up with as accurate 3.2% percent of height/width as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [Guidelines](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7#4511)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/startVerticalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.032" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/endVerticalGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.968" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottomGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.968" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#AAA"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/startVerticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/endVerticalGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomGuideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]